# convert the POSTHOC comparison pairs to Compact letter display?

Tags: python, r, excel-formula

As given by metaboanalyst, I need to convert the list of significant pairs in posthoc as given by metaboanalyst to asign compact display letters for each group automaticaly

GRP1 - GRP2; GRP1 - GRP4; GRP1 - GRP3; GRP1 - CTRL; CTRL - GRP4

to

CTRL GRP1 GRP2 GRP3 GRP4
b a bc bc c

I tried in excel by assigning values but there's a lot of combinations